# How to get a file's content of UNO shared project as string

Tags: c#, webassembly, uno-platform

In regular C#/UWP it is possible without any (bigger) problems to read a file's (or resource's) content to a string variable. How is this done with the UNO platform's WebAssembly build target?

What I already tried: According to the browser's debugging console, my code execution stops (without any exception thrown) as soon as I try to use reflection, for example. Before digging deeper in the JavaScript jungle, I decided to ask the specialists here.
(As a last workaround, I thought about using the HTTP client implementation, but I will do this only if there really is no usable alternative.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WebAssembly target for Uno does not support reading content files for now as part of the `System.IO.File` api (and probably won't in the near future because of its synchronous API).

The easiest way, which works cross platforms, is to use embedded resources:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="myfile.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then in the code, use something like this:

```
static string ReadResource(string fileName)
{
    var assembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;
    var resourceName = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
        .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Contains(fileName));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceName))
    {
        using (var s = new StreamReader(assembly .GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)))
        {
            return s.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            $"Unable to find resource {fileName} in {typeof(Program).Assembly}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost: You need to insert "!" before "string.IsNullOrEmpty".

:-)